# MyBatis throws exception "stream closed"

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a java application that runs as a cron. It uses MyBatis. In my mybatis-config.xml, I have

```
<environments default="staging">
        <environment id="prod_read">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.2:3306/myDB"/>
                <property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
                <property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
        <environment id="prod_write">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.1:3306/myDB"/>
                <property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
                <property name="password" value="dbpass"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
        <environment id="staging">.....
</environments>
```

So, I am using 2 DBs in production - one for read slave and one for write master.

In the code, the initialization of the SqlSessionFactory is like this

```
InputStream rd = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream(mybatisConfigXml);

try {
    sessionFactory_read = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(rd, Main.DB_ENV + "_read");
    sessionFactory_write = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(rd, Main.DB_ENV + "_write");
}catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When this code runs, I get an exception at the **_write** initialization with the message

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

How do I resolve this issue? Which stream is it talking about as being closed? Should I create 2 instances of InputStream (rd1, rd2) and use them in the 2 SqlSessionFactory initializations?
I have checked the DB credentials and they are alright.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you pass stream of mybatis configuration xml two times to `SqlSessionFactoryBuilder`. During the first invocation the stream is read fully and closed so during the second invocation you get `stream is closed` exception.

You need to open stream again.